# Does this insert call leak connections

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-connection, connection-pooling

Does this insert call leak connections

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("foo");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();

try {
    transaction.begin();
     // insert call goes here
    em.flush();
    transaction.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
} finally {
    if (em != null) {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: they aren't, this is different and is on a insert. Does the code snippet look ok? I still seem to have connection leaks on my standalone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection leaks are because of creating any connection and keeping those open, your code seems right to me.

Consider this : Finally is not always executed. It is not executed in following cases.

1. When JVM exits when try catch block is being executed.
2. If thread executing try catch block is interrupted or killed.